# 2004 Acura TSX. Locating a missing unplugged wire under hood?

Tags: engine, acura, hood, tsx

Bought a used Acura and I was looking under the hood and found this unplugged wire. It's orange and right behind the fuse. It's bunched up with other wires.

Is it just and extra cable that doesn't plug into anything?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is likely for something not fitted on your car. For manufacturing cost savings wiring harnesses are made so that they can fit a number of different versions of the car. Unused bits are just left unplugged.